# Cannot load specific icon from `SAP-icons.ttf` font

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to display SAP icon(please see link to the attachment) from custom font. I've added custom font `SAP-icons.ttf` to the project(it's included in bundle and loaded correctly, double checked), but I cannot load the correct symbol.

The code snippet that I use is below:

Get path to the font. It's stored in specific bundle. Get reference using CGDataProvider.

```
NSString *fontPath = [[NSBundle my_currentBundle]     pathForResource:@"SAP-icons" ofType:@"ttf"];

CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithFilename([fontPath UTF8String]);
CGFontRef fontRef = CGFontCreateWithDataProvider(provider);
CFErrorRef error = nil;
if (! CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont(fontRef, &error)) {
    CFStringRef errorDescription = CFErrorCopyDescription(error);
    NSLog(@"Failed to load font: %@", errorDescription);
    CFRelease(errorDescription);
}
```

Get font name and create UIFont object.

```
NSString *fontName = (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CGFontCopyPostScriptName(fontRef));
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:20];

CFRelease(fontRef);
CFRelease(provider);
```

For desired icon I found `&#xe202` referenced unicode in site with the link below:
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/iconExplorer.html#/?tab=grid&search=info&icon=message-information

If `&#xe202` unicode value is incorrect for this icon which should I use? 
I can't event preview installed `SAP-icons` font characters in my Mac - all of them are `question marks`!

```
char *iconUnicodeStr = "&#xe202";
NSString *infoIconString = [NSString stringWithCString: iconUnicode encoding:(NSUnicodeStringEncoding)];
```

Apply specific font, set text. Result - incorrect symbol.

```
[self.button.titleLabel setFont:font];
[self.button.titleLabel setTitle:infoIconString];
```

Thanks in advance for any help and suggestions how could I do that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Instead of**

```
char *iconUnicodeStr = "U+xe202";
label.text = [NSString stringWithCString:iconUnicodeStr encoding:(NSUnicodeStringEncoding)];
```

**Use**

```
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", (unichar)0xe202];
```

And not to forget set the font for the label

```
label.font = myCustomFont;
```

Comment: Sure, please see the [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l42r0fu37hkj27v/SAP_icons.ttf?dl=0). Note: strange think is I cannot view font icons in Font Book.

Comment: If you go to Font Book and choose Validate Font file, it says it is all right. But for some reason you can see the font. No idea why.

Comment: Could you try: label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", (unichar)0xe125];      ? it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure problem lies in the font name.

```
for (NSString *familyName in [UIFont familyNames]){
    NSLog(@"Family name: %@", familyName);
    for (NSString *fontName in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:familyName]) {
        NSLog(@"--Font name: %@", fontName);
    }
}
```

Run above code in AppDelegate didFinish and make  sure you are using correct font name.

***Search for SAP_icons in the NSLog from above code. If you don't find look for the proper name.***

Search for SAP in above log, that will give you correct name.